# Storing objects in 2 dimensional sprite matrix in c++

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I want to store a list of tiles (pointers to objects of class "Sprite") in a two dimensional vector.

Currently I'm storing all the sprites of my tilemap in a vector.

```
std::vector<Sprite*> _tiles;
```

Now I need to get all the neighbored tiles and I thought it be easier, to store my sprites in a 2d matrix (vector in vector) to do those caluclations.

But I can't figure out how to do that.

Header:

```
private:
  std::vector<std::vector<Sprite*>> matrix;
```

C++ File:

```
vectorMatrix::vectorMatrix(int columns, int rows) { }

vectorMatrix::~vectorMatrix() { } 


void vectorMatrix::addCellAt(int x, int y, Sprite* sprite) {
  std::vector< std::vector<Sprite*> > matrix;
  matrix[x][y].push_back(sprite);
}
```

But I get an error message if I use two index operators.

Comment: `matrix[x][y]` gives you a `Sprite *`. You should probably assign to it using `=` instead, and switch to using `std::shared_ptr` to avoid memory leaks from not freeing the data.

Comment: You have not allocated spaces for the matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
std::vector< std::vector<Sprite*> > matrix;
```

This is an empty std::vector of  of std::vector, and as others have pointed out, it's no longer the data member matrix.

Since it's empty, it's not possible to do `matrix[0]` - get the first row, `matrix[1]` - get the second row... You can however allocate the size of the matrix in your constructor first -- e.g. This will give you a `rows*columns` matrix

```
vectorMatrix::vectorMatrix(int columns, int rows) 
  : matrix(rows, std::vector<Sprite*>(columns))
{
}
```

And then you can set the xth and yth element to the corresponding `Sprite*`, and of course `x` and `y` should be smaller than `rows` and `columns`

```
matrix[x][y] = sprite;
```

And don't declare `matrix` again inside the `addCellAt`, You can use the data members directly anywhere inside the class.

Answer (score 1):

Three problems:

1. You declare a *local* variable `matrix` inside the function, which shadows the member variable.
2. If the size of the vectors is not set to include the `x` and `y` indexes then you will go out of bounds.
3. `matrix[x][y]` is not itself a vector, it's an element that you can assign directly:

   ```
   matrix[x][y] = sprite;
   ```

   Remember to consider problem 2 before doing this.

Comment: the local matrix was a copy and paste error... sry - thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think it's a good idea to make your matrix a vector-of-vectors? True, this will "work" in the sense that `vec_of_vec_matrix[i][j]` will return the right thing, but it's somewhat cumbersome and inefficient.

Instead, consider basing your class on a *single* vector - of all data, as done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2076668/1593077) (and probably in many libraries). Element access will be something like (for column-major data):

```
Sprite*& Matrix::operator()(size_t i, size_t j)
{
    return mData[i * num_columns + j];
}
```

You could even arrange with `map[x][y]` to work, using a row proxy class.

Comment: Thank you! I found this approach in a lot of examples, that's why i wanted to use it. i don't think it's too cumbersome, but if there's a more performant approach, i'll have a look. Is the performance difference significant?  think i'll call a few operations on that tilematrix each frame, so that'd be nice to consider.

Comment: @Chris: It will very likely be perform better because element access will not require double-indirection, i.e. you'll only have one memory load, while the multiply+add is well catered for by CPUs.